# Chamada de método falhando com ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments)

Tags: ruby

```
it '1: conseguir criar um objeto Produto com catetoria geral' do
    nome = 'Bola'
    valor = 30
    produto = Produto.new(nome: nome, valor: valor)
    expect(produto.nome).to eq 'Bola'
    expect(produto.categoria).to eq 'Geral'
    expect(produto.valor).to eq 100
  end

Class produto.rb
  attr_accessor :nome, :categoria , :valor
  
  def initialize(nome, categoria,valor)
     @nome = nome
     @categoria = 'Geral'
     @valor = valor
  end
```

quando rodo teste unitário retorna. No console com irb retorna..

```
Failure/Error:
       def initialize(nome, valor)
          @nome = nome
          @categoria = 'Geral'
          @valor = valor
       end
     
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 3)
```

Answer (score -3):

O construtor da classe `Produto` espera três argumentos: `nome`, `categoria` e `valor`, conforme o método `initialize`. No teste, a linha que chama o construtor passa somente um argumento:

```
produto = Produto.new(nome: nome, valor: valor)
```

O correto é:

```
produto = Produto.new(nome, categoria, valor)
```

Da forma com que você escreveu, você está na verdade passando um único [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html). Veja o seguinte exemplo:

```
def teste(argumento)
  p argumento
end

teste(foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3)
# => {:foo=>1, :bar=>2, :baz=>3}
```

É por isso que a exceção `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 3)` é lançada. Onde espera-se três argumentos, somente um único `Hash` foi passado.

Você está tentando fazer algo parecido com [argumentos nomeados](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ruby-2-keyword-arguments), o que é possível em Ruby, mas não é padrão da linguagem.

Comment: grato, pela informação..

Comment: Gostaria de entender os votos negativos, aliás, se o objetivo é ser construtivo, preciso entender onde melhorar.